# How to create attribute in magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento, zend-framework, magento-1.9

How can we create an attribute for product programatically in magento CE 1.9? I have been trying out multiple ways for creating an attribute for product that has a boolean value by default set to false and assigned to Default attribute set, but not visible/editable by any admin panel user.

my Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Setup.php

```
    <?php

class Mofosys_Quickbuy_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup {
protected function _prepareValues($attr) {
    $data = parent::_prepareValues($attr);
    $data = array_merge($data, array(

        'apply_to'                      => $this->_getValue($attr, 'apply_to'),
        'frontend_input_renderer'       => $this->_getValue($attr, 'input_renderer'),
        'is_comparable'                 => $this->_getValue($attr, 'comparable', 0),
        'is_configurable'               => $this->_getValue($attr, 'is_configurable', 0),
        'is_filterable'                 => $this->_getValue($attr, 'filterable', 0),
        'is_filterable_in_search'       => $this->_getValue($attr, 'filterable_in_search', 0),
        'is_global'                     => $this->_getValue(
            $attr,
            'global',
            Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL
            ),
        'is_html_allowed_on_front'      => $this->_getValue($attr, 'is_html_allowed_on_front', 0),
        'is_searchable'                 => $this->_getValue($attr, 'searchable', 0),
        'is_used_for_promo_rules'       => $this->_getValue($attr, 'used_for_promo_rules', 0),
        'is_visible'                    => $this->_getValue($attr, 'visible', 0),
        'is_visible_on_front'           => $this->_getValue($attr, 'visible_on_front', 0),
        'is_wysiwyg_enabled'            => $this->_getValue($attr, 'wysiwyg_enabled', 0),
        'is_visible_in_advanced_search' => $this->_getValue($attr, 'visible_in_advanced_search', 0),
        'position'                      => $this->_getValue($attr, 'position', 0),
        'used_for_sort_by'              => $this->_getValue($attr, 'used_for_sort_by', 0),
        'used_in_product_listing'       => $this->_getValue($attr, 'used_in_product_listing', 0),
        ));
    return $data;
}
}

?>
```

my etc/config.xml

```
    <global>
        <resources>
            <mofosys_quickbuy_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Mofosys_Quickbuy</module>
                <class>Mofosys_Quickbuy_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </mofosys_quickbuy_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
```

my sql/mofosys_quickbuy_setup/install-0.0.1.php

```
    <?php
// Installer file to create an attribute name "approved" inside Default attribute set
$installer = $this;
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();


// the attribute added will be displayed under the group/tab Special Attributes in product edit page
$setup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'approved', array(
    'group'                         =>          'Default',
    'input'                         =>          'select',
    'type'                          =>          'int',
    'default'                       =>          '0',
    'label'                         =>          'Testing',
    'backend'                       =>          '',
    'visible'                       =>          0,
    'required'                      =>          0,
    'user_defined'                  =>          0,
    'searchable'                    =>          0,
    'filterable'                    =>          0,
    'comparable'                    =>          0,
    'visible_on_front'              =>          0,
    'visible_in_advanced_search'    =>          0,
    'is_html_allowed_on_front'      =>          0,
    'global'                        =>          Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
));


$installer->endSetup();

?>
```

Comment: Could you please post your code here that you did so far ?

Comment: I have put my entire code to create my attribute there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it should work, it just worked fine for me, just put this code in your install.php

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
// Set data:
$attributeName  = 'Approve'; // Name of the attribute
$attributeCode  = 'approve'; // Code of the attribute
$attributeGroup = 'General';          // Group to add the attribute to
$attributeSetIds = array(4);          // Array with attribute set ID's to add this attribute to. (ID:4 is the Default Attribute Set)

// Configuration:
$data = array(
    'type'      => 'select',       // Attribute type
    'input'     => 'boolean',          // Input type
    'global'    =>  Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,    // Attribute scope
    'required'  => false,           // Is this attribute required?
    'user_defined' => false,
    'searchable' => false,
    'filterable' => false,
    'comparable' => false,
    'visible_on_front' => false,
    'unique' => false,
    'used_in_product_listing' => true,
    'default_value_yesno' => '0',
    // Filled from above:
    'label' => $attributeName
);

// Create attribute:
// We create a new installer class here so we can also use this snippet in a non-EAV setup script.
$installer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup', 'catalog_setup');

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', $attributeCode, $data);

// Add the attribute to the proper sets/groups:
foreach($attributeSetIds as $attributeSetId)
{
    $installer->addAttributeToGroup('catalog_product', $attributeSetId, $attributeGroup, $attributeCode);
}

$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: Is there a way to add it to all groups?